# U-Boot with OpenSBI on HiFive Unleashed in QEMU: Store/AMO access fault

Tags: qemu, u-boot, riscv

I've been trying to get U-Boot to work in QEMU for the `sifive_u` machine. I've tried using both the built in OpenSBI 'BIOS' and building my own OpenSBI, but I keep running into the same issue.

I'm building U-Boot using the riscv64 toolchain from the Arch repos:

```
➜  u-boot git:(0b0c6af387) riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc --version
riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
➜  u-boot git:(0b0c6af387) export CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-linux-gnu-
➜  u-boot git:(0b0c6af387) export ARCH=riscv
➜  u-boot git:(0b0c6af387) make sifive_fu540_defconfig
...
➜  u-boot git:(0b0c6af387) make
```

I've tried to run this as follows:

```
➜  opensbi git:(master) ✗ qemu-system-riscv64 -M sifive_u -m 256M -bios default -display none -serial stdio -device loader,addr=0x80200000,file=../u-boot/u-boot.bin

OpenSBI v0.5 (Oct  9 2019 12:03:04)
   ____                    _____ ____ _____
  / __ \                  / ____|  _ \_   _|
 | |  | |_ __   ___ _ __ | (___ | |_) || |
 | |  | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \ \___ \|  _ < | |
 | |__| | |_) |  __/ | | |____) | |_) || |_
  \____/| .__/ \___|_| |_|_____/|____/_____|
        | |
        |_|

Platform Name          : SiFive Freedom U540
Platform HART Features : RV64ACDFIMSU
Platform Max HARTs     : 5
Current Hart           : 1
Firmware Base          : 0x80000000
Firmware Size          : 96 KB
Runtime SBI Version    : 0.2

PMP0: 0x0000000080000000-0x000000008001ffff (A)
PMP1: 0x0000000000000000-0xffffffffffffffff (A,R,W,X)


U-Boot 2020.01 (Jan 20 2020 - 18:14:27 +0000)

CPU:   rv64imafdc
Model: SiFive HiFive Unleashed A00
DRAM:  exception code: 7 , Store/AMO access fault , epc 8023cbdc , ra 8020c670
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

I've also tried bundling U-Boot as a payload into my own build of OpenSBI:

```
➜  opensbi git:(master) ✗ export CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-elf-
➜  opensbi git:(master) ✗ make PLATFORM=sifive/fu540 FW_PAYLOAD_PATH=../u-boot/u-boot.bin

➜  opensbi git:(master) ✗ qemu-system-riscv64 -M sifive_u -m 256M -bios none -display none -serial stdio -device loader,addr=0x80000000,file=./build/platform/sifive/fu540/firmware/fw_payload.bin


OpenSBI v0.5-32-gc0849cd
   ____                    _____ ____ _____
  / __ \                  / ____|  _ \_   _|
 | |  | |_ __   ___ _ __ | (___ | |_) || |
 | |  | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \ \___ \|  _ < | |
 | |__| | |_) |  __/ | | |____) | |_) || |_
  \____/| .__/ \___|_| |_|_____/|____/_____|
        | |
        |_|

Platform Name          : SiFive Freedom U540
Platform HART Features : RV64ACDFIMSU
Platform Max HARTs     : 5
Current Hart           : 1
Firmware Base          : 0x80000000
Firmware Size          : 100 KB
Runtime SBI Version    : 0.2

PMP0: 0x0000000080000000-0x000000008001ffff (A)
PMP1: 0x0000000000000000-0xffffffffffffffff (A,R,W,X)


U-Boot 2020.01 (Jan 20 2020 - 18:14:27 +0000)

CPU:   rv64imafdc
Model: SiFive HiFive Unleashed A00
DRAM:  exception code: 7 , Store/AMO access fault , epc 8023cbdc , ra 8020c670
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

I've tried looking at the offending instruction (which I presume is at `0x8023cbdc`) based on the error message:

```
➜  u-boot git:(0b0c6af387) riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump --start-address=0x8023cbdc -d ./u-boot | head -8

./u-boot:     file format elf64-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text_rest:

000000008023cbdc <memset+0x40>:
    8023cbdc:   fee7bc23                sd      a4,-8(a5)
```

It's a store, so it's plausible that this is indeed accessing an invalid location; I'm trying to get GDB working so I can examine what's actually happening in more detail, but that's causing issues of its own...

Has anyone had any success with this?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to fix this specific error by changing the amount of memory with `-M 2G`; I presume the address it's trying to access lies outside the 256M range, but I'm not sure what it's doing that requires this much RAM.

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
➜  opensbi git:(master) ✗ qemu-system-riscv64 -M sifive_u -m 8G -bios default -display none -serial stdio -device loader,addr=0x80200000,file=../u-boot/u-boot-dtb.bin

OpenSBI v0.5 (Oct  9 2019 12:03:04)
   ____                    _____ ____ _____
  / __ \                  / ____|  _ \_   _|
 | |  | |_ __   ___ _ __ | (___ | |_) || |
 | |  | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \ \___ \|  _ < | |
 | |__| | |_) |  __/ | | |____) | |_) || |_
  \____/| .__/ \___|_| |_|_____/|____/_____|
        | |
        |_|

Platform Name          : SiFive Freedom U540
Platform HART Features : RV64ACDFIMSU
Platform Max HARTs     : 5
Current Hart           : 1
Firmware Base          : 0x80000000
Firmware Size          : 96 KB
Runtime SBI Version    : 0.2

PMP0: 0x0000000080000000-0x000000008001ffff (A)
PMP1: 0x0000000000000000-0xffffffffffffffff (A,R,W,X)


U-Boot 2020.01 (Jan 20 2020 - 21:40:02 +0000)

CPU:   rv64imafdc
Model: SiFive HiFive Unleashed A00
DRAM:  8 GiB
MMC:   exception code: 5 , Load access fault , epc fffadbd6 , ra fffadbd2
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
qemu-system-riscv64: terminating on signal 2
```

Again it's similar (although a load this time); interestingly, the address `fffadbd6` isn't part of U-Boot so I've no idea what's happening here; I very much doubt it's running off the end, because then I would expect undefined behaviour as opposed to consistently getting the same bad load.

Comment: Its too bad the exception handler doesn't show the `mtval` (the address of attempted access).  (Also, not sure why they think `ra` is more relevant here than `mtval`??)

Comment: @ErikEidt Indeed, I tried to use GDB to observe which address is being accessed, but I'm having problems with that too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828618/remote-debugging-hifive-unleashed-in-qemu); I actually managed to fix this error, but I've run into another very similar one, I'll update the question.

Comment: @ErikEidt I might try hacking the exception handler to dump `mtval` too.

Comment: Are you still seeing the issue?

Btw there was a recent patch in U-Boot to dump all register on exception. Not sure if that is from you or somebody else.

https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1215339/

Comment: @alex sadly other work has got in the way (ihtfp). Not my patch, but I'm planning to return to this.

Comment: @p0llard sure. Let me know if you still see the issue. I run OpenSBI + U-Boot + Linux in Qemu very often. I may be able to help

Comment: @alex just wondering which toolchain you're using for cross-compiling U-Bboot?

Comment: From bootlin
https://toolchains.bootlin.com/

Comment: I voted to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

I built U-Boot 2023.07 with gcc 12.3.0-6ubuntu1 as follows:

```
export OPENSBI=../opensbi/build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_dynamic.bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-linux-gnu-
make sifive_unleashed_defconfig
make -j$(nproc)
```

I am using QEMU 8.0 which provides OpenSBI as default firmware. The following command starts U-Boot successfully:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-riscv64 -M sifive_u -m 8G -nographic \
-kernel u-boot.bin
```

To use my own OpenSBI the following works:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-riscv64 -M sifive_u -m 8G -nographic \
-bios ../opensbi/build/platform/generic/firmware/fw_dynamic.bin \
-kernel u-boot.bin
```

OpenSBI has to be built with

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-linux-gnu-
make PLATFORM=generic
```

Comment: The reason this question has not had any answers in over three years, till now, is because it is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Vote to close instead.